# Convert String to Date exception

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked a lot but I can't find the solution to mine. I have an application where I'm converting a string to a date and I always catch the exception. The string that I want to convert is in the format: `Mon, Aug 4, 2014`. Here is my code:

```
try {
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MM d, yyyy").parse(theStringToConvert);
    Log.i("MyApp", "Date: " + d);
}
catch (ParseException e){
    Log.i("EXCEPTION", "Cannot parse string");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"MM" is "two digit month". You want "MMM" for "abbreviated name of month". Additionally, you should specify the locale so that it doesn't try to parse it in the user's locale - assuming it really *will* always be English:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String text = "Mon, Aug 4, 2014";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyy",
                                                  Locale.US);
        Date date = format.parse(text);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a feeling I was just making a stupid mistake =P, Thank you!

Comment: shouldnot the day parameter be dd?

Comment: If you want any [system] locale, then use `Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale` instead of `Locale.US` (You will need to import `android.content.res.Resources`). Note: Don't use `Locale.getDefault()` as this can be overwritten by an Android app.

Comment: @IllegalArgument: Not given the sample string, which would be "Mon, Aug 04, 2004" if so. (That would be an odd format, IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at what the `ParseExeption` says exactly. Parsing your String, should be done by computers, not by humans.

Anyway, the first problem I can see is, that you must write three `M`s instead of two:
`EEE, MMM d, yyyy`.

Comment: Pretty sure he is doing with a computer, dude.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Check{
 public static void main(String args[])throws ParseException{
 String str="Mon, Aug 4, 2014";
 java.util.Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH).parse(str);
 System.out.println(date);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you string month is not digital. Parse string

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyy",Locale.US).parse(theStringToConvert);
```